left invariant vector fields
Let $G$ be  a Lie group endowed with a Riemannian metric $<,>$ that is both left and right-invariant, which is to say, left and right multiplication are isometries.
Why is it that we have $$\nabla_XX=0,\;\forall\text{ left-invariant vector fields } 
 X?$$
So, as I see, integral curves of $X$ are the geodescis of $G$?

An interesting question whose answer follows from this Proposition.
